# How to get pictures to be shown in collectiveview (Json)?

Tags: json, swift, uicollectionview

I have tried to write the app that data can be shown form Json and displayed in collectionview but the problem is only text can be displayed but not the  pictures. Can anybody assist, or give me some advice?

```
var collection = [LabelClass]()
let kiaLoandURL = "http://xxxx.com/?json=get_recent_posts/json=1&count=10&custom_fields=PostThumb&include=title,content,thumbnail"

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCollectionViewCell

cell.nameLabel.text = collection[indexPath.row].title
cell.nameImage.image = UIImage(named: collection[indexPath.row].image) // not working

 return cell
```

}

```
func parseJsonData(data:NSData) -> [LabelClass] {

        var info = [LabelClass]()
        var error:NSError?

        let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary


        if error != nil{
            println(error?.localizedDescription)
        }

        let json = jsonResult?["posts"] as [AnyObject]


        for jsonLoad in json {

            let data = LabelClass()
            data.title = jsonLoan["title"] as String
            data.image = jsonLoan["thumbnail"] as String

            info.append(data)
        }
        return info
   }
```

Comment: Have you checked `UIImage(named: "...")` isn't returning nil?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the `UIImage` function with `named:` parameter for images which are contained in your project.

You should try the method which is used here:
[Loading/Downloading image from URL on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/swift-loading-image-from-url)